# Difference using ps|wc -l with or without bash variable

Tags: bash, ps, wc

Using bash, I would like to understand the different outputs between :

```
ps |wc -l
4
```

and

```
n=$(ps|wc -l)
echo $n
5
```

I guess the `$(ps|wc -l)` instruction is creating an additional subprocess, but I don't really understand why it is addded to the ps count

Answer (score 2):

You said it: `$( )` creates a subprocess. Because the command `ps` without options precisely lists all subprocesses of the current shell, you get one more line. I checked this by replacing `wc` with `tee`:

```
$ ps | tee four

    PID TTY          TIME CMD
XXXXXXX pts/5    00:00:00 bash
YYYYYYY pts/5    00:00:00   ps
ZZZZZZZ pts/5    00:00:00   tee

$ : $(ps -H | tee five)
$ cat five

    PID TTY          TIME CMD
XXXXXXX pts/5    00:00:00 bash
YYYYYYY pts/5    00:00:00   bash
ZZZZZZZ pts/5    00:00:00     ps
ΩΩΩΩΩΩΩ pts/5    00:00:00     tee
```

I also passed `-H` to `ps` so that it evidences the process tree.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly the information I wanted to visualize. I didn't know the ":" command by the way :)